# Numpy slicing a fixed length on two axis based on different starting index given by two arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

For example, I have nparray:

```
a = np.arange(48).reshape((3,4,4))
'''
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]
  [12 13 14 15]]
 [[16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]
  [24 25 26 27]
  [28 29 30 31]]
 [[32 33 34 35]
  [36 37 38 39]
  [40 41 42 43]
  [44 45 46 47]]]
'''
```

I have two arrays that used as the starting point of slicing on axis=1, axis=2 respectively:

```
b1 = [0,1,2]
b2 = [1,0,0]
```

I want to achieve, a slicing like:

```
a[:,b1:b1+2, b2:b2+2] # but this syntax is wrong
```

To get

```
[
[
[1,2]
[5,6]
]

[
[20 21]
[24 25]
]

[
[40 41]
[44 45]
]
]
```

Please let me know if you know the proper syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the built-in functions `enumerate` with `zip`:

```
list(a[i][f:f+2, s:s+2].tolist() for i, (f, s) in enumerate(zip(b1, b2)))
```

output:

```
[[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[20, 21], [24, 25]], [[40, 41], [44, 45]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning zip, I almost got it by breaking it down to two steps without using zip, but with zip, it could be done within the list comprehension. My final solution is: `d = np.array([a[i,c1:c1+2, c2:c2+2] for i, (c1,c2) in enumerate(zip(b1,b2))])`